# How can I generate config file from frozen graph

Tags: tensorflow

I have a frozen graph (`.pb`) file , which I haven't generated . I was told that its a saved tensorflow model for a simple image classifier. Now I want to use that model with `opencv` . There is a function for opencv to load frozen graph  `cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow()`  .  Which accept two parameter one is the model itself(`.pb`) file and another is config file (`pbtxt`) file . I don't have the `pbtxt` file .

How can generate that `pbtxt` file from that `pb` file ?